# What to learn for windows programming(that doesn't require any framework installation for end-users)?

Tags: windows, frameworks

Exactly what the titles says, What should I learn to be able to create software that doesn't require any framework installation for end-user(the software user)?

So that rules out .net and Java.

What other options do i have available? Is win32 api the only way to write native applications for windows?

Does Qt require installation any installation at user end?

I am open to adapting to any programming language and framework to be able to create native applications.

Please mention the programming languages and framework I should learn to do so.

Comment: .NET 2.0 / 3.0 is included with Windows Vista & Server 2008

Comment: Can anyone please regarding Qt? Does it require framework to work on user end?

Answer (score 0):

Delphi. A superb implementaion of object-oriented Pascal, with apps that can be deployed as single .exe files.

The best way of writing native applications for Windows - and always has been.

The built-in framework (VCL) hides the complexity of the Win32 API, without preventing you from going as deep into the OS as you want to.

Answer (score 0):

C and unmanaged C++ are the most obvious choices for developing a stand-alone Windows executable. Really, any language that compiles down to executable code will work.

However, you can develop an application in Python and convert it to a standalone executable -- no external dependencies -- with [py2exe](http://www.py2exe.org/).